# How i can perform Load/Stress testing for a flash game?

Tags: flash, testing, stress-testing

I am facing some issues in load/stress testing of Flash based on line game.

How can I perform Load/Stress testing for a flash game (it may be off line or on line)?

Would you recommend any automated tool for testing a flash game?

Where I can create virtual users and define some predefine scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the way you've coded your game,
if it uses some sort of backend to process user actions
you can easily create a flash app to send out hundreds of requests to this backend
and see how it performs (I assume most game logic is stored in the backend). This app can be run on several machines simultaneously to simulate thousands of requests to the backend.
This way you can "code" the actions normally performed by users, for example "walk here" or "shoot there" etc.

For a more real life scenario i suppose you're stuck to manually testing it on as many computers as you can at the same time since overal performance also depends on the clients pc, internet connection, ping etc.

A third option could be to write a simple app to send a http request to the webserver hosting the flash file, thus requesting the page on which the flash file is loaded.
This way you can see if the server can handle a lot of simultaneous requests

Comment: thanks for your reply it will really help full for me......but 
if you know any automation tool which may create virtual uses for the load testing please tell me....?

Comment: can you tell me what you want to test exactly?
is it the load on the backend like apache or IIS
or do you want to test your flash files 
or do you need to stresstest a custom game backend?